# IBM Watson issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Could someone helpme with this issue
This is my code

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:Zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ^
--header "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8" ^
--header "Accept: application/json" ^
--data-binary @profile.txt ^
"https:/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1a/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13"
```

This is the error

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - La función de revocación no puede comprobar la revocación para el certificado.
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, provide more details

Answer (score 0):

That is a fairly basic curl error in that it doesn't understand what you are trying.

I think you are running your command over multiple lines. Curl is a single line command. The line markings you see in the samples are line continuations. The format for line continuations differs environment to environment. If you don't know the line continuation marker for your environment then run the command on a single line eg.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --data-binary @profile.json "{url}/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```